# Delete all the keys of ehcache

Tags: rest, apache-camel, ehcache, spring-camel

I'm using Ehcache with Apache camel. I'm exposing a rest endpoint which should delete all the keys from Ehcache. For some reason, its not deleting the keys after calling the rest endpoint.

Following code is being used to achieve the same :

```
<restConfiguration component="servlet"
            bindingMode="json" />
        <rest path="/clear">
            <get uri="/ehcache">
                <to uri="direct:clear_ehcache" />
            </get>
        </rest>
<route id="clear_ehcache_001">
            <from uri="direct:clear_ehcache" />
            <setHeader headerName="CamelCacheOperation">
                <constant>CamelCacheDeleteAll</constant>
            </setHeader>
            <setHeader headerName="CamelEhcacheAction">
                <constant>REMOVE_ALL</constant>
            </setHeader>
            <to uri="ehcache://mycache" />  
</route>
```

I've been stuck on this for a while now as there are no errors generated.

Answer (score 0):

So it worked with the following piece of code instead :

```
<!-- Rest endpoint for clearing ehcache : Start -->
<restConfiguration component="servlet"
    bindingMode="json" />
<rest path="/clear">
    <get uri="/ehcache">
        <to uri="direct:clear_ehcache" />
    </get>
</rest>
<!-- Rest endpoint for clearing ehcache : End -->

<!-- Route for clearing ehcache : Start -->
<route id="clear_ehcache_001">
    <from uri="direct:clear_ehcache" />
    <log id="_logging_clear_ehcache"
        message="Clearing Ehcache records.." />
    <setHeader headerName="CamelEhcacheAction"
        id="getCamelEhCacheAction003">
        <constant>CLEAR</constant>
    </setHeader>
    <to id="_to4"
        uri="ehcache://mycache?keyType=java.lang.String&amp;valueType=java.lang.String" />

</route>
<!-- Route for clearing ehcache : End -->
```